# Truth evaluation of any type of variable

Tags: python, numpy

How does one simply verify that some variable is not False, regardless of whether the variable is an array, list, integer, or whatever? For instance:

```
import numpy as np

a = 1
b = False
c = np.array([1, 2])

def myFunction(var):
    if var:
        print('var is something, but it's not False')

myFunction(a)
myFunction(b)
myFunction(c)
```

This returns the error message "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()." for c. If I use var.all(), then the code will only work with an array. There must be some evaluation method that doesn't care what type of variable is given. I know that I could use try, but this will require multiple lines of code and seems very non-Pythonic for an apparently simple task.

For some context, sometimes I want to execute a piece of code only so long as that variable actually has a value. If it has no value, perhaps it is False by default, then I want to execute a different piece of code.

Comment: In Python all variables have a value, otherwise you'd get a `NameError`.  `None` is perhaps the closest thing to `no value`.  It tests `False`, but `isNone` is often preferable.  Each object class potentially has its own `False`.

Comment: Use the `try` Luke!

Comment: Multiple lines of code to test the type of inputs is quite normal in Python.  The more general the function is, in terms of what it accepts as input, the complicated will be the tests, assuming it is supposed to something rational with each kind.  The safest default is `def foo(y=none):`.

Comment: To be clear, you want to test for falsiness (or lack thereof) or do you want to test for False? "regardless of whether the variable is an array, list, integer, or whatever" sounds like you just want falsiness but its not clear...

Comment: "For some context, sometimes I want to execute a piece of code only so long as that variable actually has a value" - testing whether a thing is False isn't going to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen Rauch suggested, maybe with `try`:

```
def myFunction(var):
    try:
        if var==False: #If raises an exception, will jump to except
            print("var is something, and it IS False")
        else:
            print("var is something, and it's not False")
    except:
        print("var is something, and it's not False")
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Python docs, https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

```
Any object [of builtin type] can be tested for truth value, 
for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.

By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines 
either a __bool__() method that returns False or a __len__() method 
that returns zero, when called with the object.
```

It lists various builtin objects that are considered `false`: `None`, `False`, `0`, `[],`{}`.

Every variable has a `value`, that is, references an object.  There's no such thing as an uninitialized variable in Python.  You'll get a `NameError` if you try use a variable that hasn't been assigned.

`None` is a good `default` value, for example in:

```
def foo(x, y=None):
    if y is None:
       y = 'a special value'
    ...
```

---

A `numpy` array is not a builtin type, and doesn't work well with this truth-value-testing.  An `ndarray` always has a value.

Here are some cases:

A single element array, regardless of dimensions (0,1,...) works in an `if`:

```
In [73]: if np.array([0]): print('yes')   # np.array(False), etc
In [74]: if np.array([1]): print('yes')
yes
```

But multielement array will produce a ValueError, regardless of the values:

```
In [75]: if np.array([1,2]): print('yes')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-1212b980c1b6> in <module>()
----> 1 if np.array([1,2]): print('yes')

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

An empty array (0 elements) is also a special case:

```
In [77]: if np.array([]): print('yes')
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous. Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
```

That `ValueError` comes up often on SO.  Typically it's in:

```
if x<0:
   ...
```

where `x` is an array.  `<` tests each value, and produces a boolean array.  `numpy` raises that error when such an array occurs in a context that expects a scalar boolean: `if`, `and`, `or`.

One possibility is to follow the `is None` test with:

```
if isinstance(y, np.ndarray):
    <specialized array testing>
elif y:
    <builtin False>
else:
    <truthy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def test(x):
  return type(x) != bool or x
```

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: This is how "one simply verify that some variable is not False, regardless of whether the variable is an array, list, integer, or whatever".

Answer (score 0):

Great! The question was essentially: Within an if statement, how do I do a True evaluation of any type of variable just to make sure I haven't already defined that variable as false? This is a quite simple solution:

```
def test(x):
  return type(x) != bool or x

if test(False):
    print('False will NOT cause execution')
else:
    print('False will NOT cause execution')

if test(True):
    print('True will cause execution')

if test(np.array([])):
    print('An empty array will cause execution')

if test(np.array([1, 2])):
    print('The test works for long arrays.')

print('\n')
```

This seems to be the simplest solution to the initial problem, but it seems a bit forced and might confuse a different person who later reads the code. I think it was inappropriate for me to set some variables to False by default in functions. A better solution would be to set them to None instead. That allows for the following solution:

```
def test2(x):
    if x is not None:
        return True

if test2(False):
    print('False WILL cause execution')

if test2(True):
    print('True will cause execution')

if test2(np.array([])):
    print('An empty array will cause execution')

if test2(np.array([1, 2])):
    print('The test works for long arrays.')
```

In this case, False will cause code to execute. Doing this, my function can activate certain bits of code only as long as I actually provided that variable to my function. Both of these solutions work with arrays of any size, which solves the dilemma.

With that problem solved, it makes me wonder how most people make it so that certain parts of code only run so long as a certain variable is provided. Perhaps there is a more standard solution.